# Best OS X TODO app that can be synced with Android?

Tags: macos, software-recommendation, data-synchronization, android

Which is the best OS X "TO DO"-app that I can sync my Android device with?

Comment: If these answers don't satisfy your question, I suggest that you flag your post and ask a moderator to try your luck by moving it to [Android.SE](http://android.stackexchange.com/). You're asking a third party app question to support your Android phone, that just happens to need to run on Apple's Desktop OS. But on Android, the OS is irrelevant (by which I mean Android users use all major operating systems and then some), more people use your type of phone, and everything desktop wise is 'third party'.

Something to consider, is all :).

Comment: Also, there is no "best". Because your opinion of best may differ wildly from someone else's.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I recommend [Wunderlist](http://www.6wunderkinder.com/wunderlist/). It has apps for Mac OSX, Windows, iPhone, iPad and yes Android. It can sync all between these different platforms. By the way it's free.

Answer (score 0):

Try out [Evernote](http://www.evernote.com/). It is free. I am pretty sure it can sync between Android and Mac. I cannot test it myself - I do not have an Android device.

Answer (score 0):

Try iCloud [Calendar and Reminder sync](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.tai.tran.calendar.free) I developed it.Trusted with more than 200k downloads.